# Xamarin.Forms UI Test - Tap Button multiple (5) times

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'm working on writing an UI-Test for my Xamarin.Forms Application.
Therefore I need to tap a button 5-times. This invokes a dialog and I need the result of the user's input to this dialog.In code I realised this by implementing an GestureRecognizer:

```
private bool HandleMultipleTouch()
{
    if (iLastTap == null || (DateTime.Now - iLastTap.Value).Milliseconds < iToleranceInMs)
    {
        if (NumberOfTaps == 4)
        {
            NumberOfTaps = 0;
            iLastTap = null;
            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            NumberOfTaps++;
            iLastTap = DateTime.Now;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NumberOfTaps = 0;
        iLastTap = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do you know any method how to use Xamarin.UITest to get the button taped 5 times in a short time? 
I tried used double tap twice and one single tap, but this is not working because of the time needed to execute the taps.

Comment: You can use `if(NumberOfTaps==1||NumberOfTaps ==2||NumberOfTaps ==3||NumberOfTaps ==4)
return:`

Comment: I think that you misunderstood me. The method you can see below is working correctly. 
What I need is a solution for my Xamarin.Forms UI Test to get this method called.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I had to tap a morse code using Xamarin.UITest and concluded that it's impossible to ensure consistent timing between taps. My solution was therefore to abandon the morse code and only check in the app whether the button was hit 5 times.